# AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, image-classification

I am trying to make a plant classification program in Python w/ TF and I came across the error mentioned in the title.

I get the following output when I build & run the program:

```
5539
2021-06-02 12:33:37.608529: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\AlphaTango\myclassifier.py", line 9, in <module>
    (feature, labels) = load_data()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\AlphaTango\utils.py", line 46, in load_data
    data = pick.load(pick)
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'load'
```

I also get a red flag on line 9 (the line with "(feature, labels) = load_data()", stating "File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\AlphaTango\myclassifier.py", line 9, in )

The code itself is pretty long, but I am going to paste it below; hopefully it will help you identify the issue and assist me:

```py
    from utils import load_data
    
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    (feature, labels) = load_data()
    
    
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feature, labels, test_size = 0.1)
    
    categories = ['black-grass', 'charlock', 'cleavers', 'common chickweed', 'common wheat', 'fat hen', 'loose silky-bent', 'maize', 'scentless mayweed', 'shepherds purse', 'small-flowered cranesbill', 'sugar beet']
    
    
    input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input([224, 224, 3])
    
    conv1=tf.kears.layers.Conv2D(filters= 32, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='Same', 
        activation ='relu')(input_layer)
    
    pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    
    conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters= 64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='Same',
        activation='relu')(pool1)
    
    pool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size(2,2), strides=(2,2))(conv2)
    
    conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 96, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='Same',
        activation='relu')(pool2)
    pool3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2))(conv3)
    
    
    conv4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 96, kernel_size= (3,3),padding='Same',
        activation= 'relu')(pool3)
    
    pool4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size(2,2), strides=(2,2))(conv4)
    
    flt1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pool4)
    
    dn1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(flt1)
    out = tf.kera.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(dn1)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, out)
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 100, epochs =10)
    
    model.save('mymodel.h5')
```

EDIT: Oh, one more thing; I was following this tutorial when building my solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POO1gdUJ7yE&t=995s

However, his code works while mine doesn't

EDIT2: Added the code of the other file as well:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import pickle



data_dir = './data/plants'

categories = ['black-grass', 'charlock', 'cleavers', 'common chickweed', 'common wheat', 'fat hen', 'loose silky-bent', 'maize', 'scentless mayweed', 'shepherds purse', 'small-flowered cranesbill', 'sugar beet']

data = []

def make_data():
    for category in categories:
        path = os.path.join(data_dir, category)  # ./data/plants/black-grass"
        label = categories.index(category)

        for img_name in os.listdir(path):
            image_path = os.path.join(path, img_name)
            image = cv2.imread(image_path)

            try:
                image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))

                image = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32)

                data.append([image, label])

            except Exception as e:
                pass

    print(len(data))

    pik = open('data.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(data, pik)
    pik.close()


make_data()

def load_data():
    pick = open('data.pickle', 'rb')
    data = pick.load(pick)
    pick.close()

    np.random.shuffle(data)

    feature = []
    labels = []

    for img, label in data:
        feature.append(img)
        labels.append(label)

    feature = np.array(feature, dtype=np.float32)
    labels = np.array(labels)

    feature = feature/255.0

    return [feature, labels]
```

Comment: it is obvious that the error is about `load_data`

Comment: Can you send that code, please? Also, the part after the 9th line isn't related to problem

Comment: One second, I'll paste the code of the other file (utils.py) in the main question.

Thanks a lot for the support! I apologize for any useless additional code or details; I'm barely a beginner.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to simplify code before posting to stack overflow, this can for example mean simplifying network architecture. Making questions short and therefore significant will increase the chance of others willingness to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo here:

```
pick = open('data.pickle', 'rb')
data = pick.load(pick) # this line
```

instead of using `pickle` to load file, you have used `pick`. Correct version is this:

```
pick = open('data.pickle', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(pick)
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the code; I also had a typo (kears instead of keras) in a certain section of the code; now I get some different errors regarding pool_size (and the fact that I do not have GPU libraries; I'll see how I can fix this).

Apparently I can't add that stuff into the main thread so I'll try to fit it in here:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\AlphaTango\myclassifier.py", line 27, in <module>
    pool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size(2,2), strides=(2,2))(conv2)
NameError: name 'pool_size' is not defined`

Comment: Another typo...apparently I forgot to add an equal sign after pool_size...

Comment: I get the following output now (had to paste it on PB because I can't edit my main thread anymore:

https://pastebin.com/9qpCW0KB